# How can I access the parent in the jquery on selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```js
$('#temp_modals').on('mouseleave','*[data-username]',function() {
    ///my logic
});
```

However I need to to have **the mouseleave event** on the the parent div of `*[data-username]`.

As this element is added dynamically to the webpage I cannot use a normal selector and need to use the $.on.

In short I want to achieve that code like this runs.

```js
$('#temp_modals').on('mouseleave','*[data-username]'.parent(),function() {
    ///my logic
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('#temp_modals').on('mouseleave','*:has(> [data-username])',function(event) {
    ///my logic
    // this should get you the parent.
    $(event.target).parent();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pn9w6/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec this should work

http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

```
$('#temp_modals').on('mouseleave','*[data-username]:parent',function() {
    ///my logic
});
```

EDIT : Indeed this won't work, thanks for pointing it out, :parent doesn't do what i was expected. This will work :

```
$('#temp_modals').on('mouseleave',$('*[data-username]').parent(),function() {
    console.log(this)
});
```

Comment: according to the specs, `:parent` selects elements who do have children